# How to simulate outlook clients

Tags: html, email, html-email

Its 2021 and this is painful. Is there anyway for me to quickly preview a HTML email?

Litmus is too expensive to justify at the moment. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps one of the newer once of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=simulate+outlook+client+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: There are several email testing tools besides Litmus.

Comment: Precisely what my question was asking.

Answer (score 8):

On top of [Litmus](http://litmus.com/), you can try [Email on Acid](http://emailonacid.com/) or [Testi.at](https://testi.at/) which provide similar testing services at a lower cost (and with a free trial as well).

If you really want to test at no cost, you can try to use Windows Mail on Windows 10 which use the same rendering engine (Word) as Outlook and match 95% of its behavior. If you're not on Windows 10, you can use a [free virtual machine provided by Microsoft on Modern.ie](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) (normally for testing IE and Edge, but it also includes Windows Mail so you can use it that way).

Comment: Windows Mail is the way to go here. I'm a Mac developer but I have a cheapo hand-me-down Toshiba laptop where I do my Windows testing. The prices the email marketing places want these days is highway robbery.

Comment: Just to add to this, Mac developer here with no access to a windows computer. Opening the html with microsoft work did the trick for me, the MS word preview looks the same as the screenshot of the tester using Outlook on windows

Answer (score 0):

You can do preview for free with  [sendinblue.com](http://sendinblue.com)

Just create an account, then go to template -> new template -> Code your own  -> Past your code -> Continue -> Preview -> Preview on different email clients

And the you will see screenshot for various email client:

More information here: https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/209554025-How-to-test-your-email-campaign

Of course they not provide all features provide by litmus