# how to test email design for Windows Outlook App on Macbook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, outlook, html-email, desktop-application

I am trying to fix some of the email css issues that Windows Outlook App has in my email html. But I am wondering if it's possible to see the preview on Macbook Pro for the email how it'd look on Microsoft Outlook App.

I am working on Rails App Email Template.

I installed `Outlook` on Macbook, and also had a look on Windows but both has quite different result.

Comment: If you installed Outlook as a separate program, you are correct to say that is different to the Windows Outlook program. But it's not the app. Outlook has an app on Android and one on Apple. I believe what you're asking for is "How to test for Windows Outlook Desktop on Macbook"? Please edit your question.

Comment: Would you be happy to pay for a service like Litmus or Email on Acid? They are proper testing environments

Comment: I gave an answer for a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834078/how-to-simulate-outlook-clients/65897816#65897816